# PermCheck Codility

Tags: javascript, programming-challenge, combinatorics

The following code gets 100% on the [PermCheck task on Codility](https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/4-counting_elements/perm_check/). It should be O(N).

The question is:

> A non-empty array A consisting of N integers is given.
>
> A permutation is a sequence containing each element from 1 to N once,
>   and only once.
>
> For example, array A such that:
>
> ```
> A[0] = 4
> A[1] = 1
> A[2] = 3
> A[3] = 2
> ```
>
> is a permutation, but array A such that:
>
> ```
> A[0] = 4
> A[1] = 1
> A[2] = 3
> ```
>
> is not a permutation, because value 2 is missing.
>
> The goal is to check whether array A is a permutation.
>
> Write a function:
>
> ```
> function solution(A);
> ```
>
> that, given an array A, returns 1 if array A is a permutation and 0 if
>   it is not.
>
> For example, given array A such that:
>
> ```
> A[0] = 4
> A[1] = 1
> A[2] = 3
> A[3] = 2
> ```
>
> the function should return 1.
>
> Given array A such that:
>
> ```
> A[0] = 4
> A[1] = 1
> A[2] = 3
> ```
>
> the function should return 0.
>
> Write an efficient algorithm for the following assumptions:
>
> - N is an integer within the range [1..100,000];
> - each element of array A is an integer within the range [1..1,000,000,000].

Let me know if you think it can be improved, but I think it is pretty good. ;)

```
function solution(A) {
    let m = A.length;
    let sumA = A.reduce((partial_sum, a) => partial_sum + a);
    let B = Array.apply(null, Array(m)).map(function () {});
    var sum_indices = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        B[A[i] - 1] = true;
        sum_indices += i + 1;
    }
    if (sum_indices == sumA && B.indexOf(undefined) == -1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Summing the arrays is not necessary.   You only need to check that the input's maximum and length are equal, and that it's free of duplicates.

This approach scores 100% as well.  It saves a couple of array traversals and exits earlier when a duplicate exists.

```
function solution(A) {
    var max = 0,
        seen = Array( A.length );
    for (var i of A) {
        if (i>max) max=i;
        if (seen[i]) return 0;
        seen[i]=true;
    }
    return +(max == A.length);
}
```

Comment: Good solution though I would consider a map or set instead of array for your seen variable, as intent would probably be a little clearer.

Comment: @MikeBrant I tried it before posting, but arrays of integers (or booleans) are very hard to beat, performance-wise.  Using a set was about 4x slower.  That said, it *does* make the code tidier.  See Blindman67's solution for a good example.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to reduce the mean complexity.

There are also several opportunities to exit the function early.

- When a duplicate is found
- When a value is found greater than the array length

Thus we get...

```
function solution(A) {
    const found = new Set();
    for (const num of A) {
        if (found.has(num) || num > A.length) { return 0 }
        found.add(num);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I think your final conditional is not even needed and you can just `return 1` after the loop exits.

Comment: @OhMyGoodness Yes. good point.

Comment: `if (len > 1e5) { return 0 }` is redundant, given the assumptions

Comment: @AndréWerlang Ah yes I see N is the max array length, not the max valid sequence size. No point holding length in `len` so almost nothing left of the function.